# Стоять В воротах или НА воротах - как правильно?

Tags: предлоги, управление

Как правильно: стоять **в** воротах или стоять **на** воротах?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет правильного и не правильного. Был и ещё вариант для вратаря, где он «часовым поставлен у ворот». Суть в следующем: на практике естественная подвижность вратаря в игре около ворот (на территории) диктует форму «стоит на воротах», а временное неподвижное положение (угловой, штрафной удары), а иногда фиксированное правилами нахождение на линии ворот (пенальти), обязывает говорить — «в воротах». Это же мы слышим от комментатора на старте игры: «В воротах "Ювентуса" — Буффон», — и видим, что вратарь занял своё место в воротах.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду спортивный контекст, футбол в первую очередь, вратарь стоит именно "на воротах", объясняется историческим использованием предлога "на" (ср. "на страже", "на посту"). Когда-то давно это слово "вратарь" означало приставленного к воротам человека, этакого сторожа ворот, занимавшегося примерно тем же, что сейчас делает обслуживающий механический шлагбаум: открывал и закрывал ворота по мере надобности. И вот такой человек именно стоял и именно "на воротах" - по тогдашнему значению предлога "на" - близкое к современному "при воротах". Потом перенесли на футбол.

Сейчас постепенно выходит из употребления, ибо слово "стоять" здесь противоестественно, вратарь не стоит, он играет.

Что же касается других видов спорта, то там употреблялось реже - в зависимости от вида спорта. Если в хоккее "стоять" в/на воротах еще как-то можно (причем скорее именно "**в** воротах"), то в водном поло это совсем уж дико звучит.

Что касается всяких других ворот, то там значения, понятно, разные, использование - в зависимости от смысла.

Comment: Дорогой г-н @Morkovkin, ваш экскурс в седую древность чрезвычайно интересен, но неплохо бы указать источник, где вратарь был "эдаким сторожем ворот". А также и "выход из употребления", и "противоестественность" надо бы доказать. Хотя бы попытаться.

Comment: @Niemand Пока - без комментариев. Я вам отвечу, когда и если вы научитесь общаться без дешевых подначек.

Comment: Какие подначки, г-н @Morkovkin? Зачем же говорить о том, в чем вы совсем не разбираетесь? Скажу по секрету: и в водном поло в воротах именно "стоят", как ни дико это (для вас) звучит. Устойчивое сочетание – великая вещь, оно почти любую "дикость" может побороть.

Comment: @Niemand без комментариев. Задавайте конкретные вопросы в нейтральном стиле и не судите, кто в чем не разбирается. Этим вы провоцируете конфликт.

Answer (score 1):

1) Если речь идет о футболе, **то возможны оба варианта, но, я думаю, больше подходит "стоять на воротах" (по аналогии "стоять на  посту").** Это устойчивое выражение со значением "быть вратарем", то есть защищать ворота, находясь во вратарской площадке.

**Примеры**:

[Как правильно стоять на воротах](https://elhow.ru/sport/sportivnye-igry/kak-stojat-na-vorotah)

Нацкорпус [стоять на воротах | ruscorpora.ru](http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%F2%EE%FF%EB%20%ED%E0%20%E2%EE%F0%EE%F2%E0%F5)

**"Стоять в воротах"** также используется: Я стоял в воротах, а Сашка был в нападении. [Владимир Железников. Жизнь и приключения чудака (1974)]. Однако  это выражение **может иметь прямой смысл**: Алпатыч садился в кибиточку. Хозяин стоял в воротах. [Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир. ] Поэтому "стоять в воротах" не очень подходит для постоянно перемещающегося в игре вратаря.

2) В то же время, например, в хоккейной коробке площадь ворот маленькая, перемещение ограниченное, поэтому  можно сказать **"стоять в воротах".**

Comment: «"быть вратарем", то есть защищать ворота, находясь во вратарской площадке.»

Защищать ворота можно, находясь в любой точке поля, и вратарю тем труднее это сделать, чем он более задвинул себя в ворота. Правильный голкипер — хозяин всей штрафной площадки.